# How to use query in Adf copy activity by using .net sdk?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created a copy activity pipeline using Portal UI is working fine with query as a source.
when I tried this with .net sdk I don't know how to use query inside copy activity, can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Below example shows create “Copy Activity” using .net sdk

```
// Create a Pipeline with Copy Activity  
Console.WriteLine("Creating pipeline " + pipelineName + "...");  
PipelineResource pipeline = new PipelineResource  
{  
    Activities = new List<Activity>  
    {  
        new CopyActivity  
        {  
            Name = "CopyFromBlobToCosmosDB",  
            Inputs = new List<DatasetReference>  
            {  
                new DatasetReference()  
                {  
                    ReferenceName = blobDatasetName  
                }  
            },  
            Outputs = new List<DatasetReference>  
            {  
                new DatasetReference  
                {  
                    ReferenceName = cosmosDbDatasetName  
                }  
            },  
            Source = new BlobSource { },  
            Sink = new DocumentDbCollectionSink { }  
        }  
    }  
};  
client.Pipelines.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, pipelineName, pipeline);  
Console.WriteLine(SafeJsonConvert.SerializeObject(pipeline, client.SerializationSettings));
```

You can find code and more information in this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-azure-data-factory-and-pipeline-using-net-sdk/) by Sarathlal Saseendran.

For Query Copy Activity in dot net,  It depends on what is Source and Sink in Copy Activity. There are number of API’s for different Source and Sink.

API for MySQL as Sink

`classazure.mgmt.datafactory.models.AzureMySqlSink(*, additional_properties=None, write_batch_size=None, write_batch_timeout=None, sink_retry_count=None, sink_retry_wait=None, max_concurrent_connections=None, pre_copy_script=None, **kwargs)`

Bases: `azure.mgmt.datafactory.models._models_py3.CopySink`

A copy activity Azure MySql sink.

All required parameters must be populated in order to send to Azure.

**Parameters**

•   **additional_properties (dict[str, object])** – Unmatched properties from the message are deserialized this collection

•   **write_batch_size (object)** – Write batch size. Type: integer (or Expression with resultType integer), minimum: 0.

•   **write_batch_timeout (object)** – Write batch timeout. Type: string (or Expression with resultType string), pattern: ((d+).)?(dd):(60|([0-5][0-9])):(60|([0-5][0-9])).

•   **sink_retry_count (object)** – Sink retry count. Type: integer (or Expression with resultType integer).

•   **sink_retry_wait (object)** – Sink retry wait. Type: string (or Expression with resultType string), pattern: ((d+).)?(dd):(60|([0-5][0-9])):(60|([0-5][0-9])).

•   **max_concurrent_connections (object)** – The maximum concurrent connection count for the sink data store. Type: integer (or Expression with resultType integer).

•   **type (str)** – Required. Constant filled by server.

•   **pre_copy_script (object)** – A query to execute before starting the copy. Type: string (or Expression with resultType string).

For more API's follow this [link](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-mgmt-datafactory/0.10.0/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.html)